# Cassandra modeling with key and indexes

Tags: sql, cassandra, pagination, many-to-many, nosql

I've a table of "Users" each user has many "Projects" and each project has many "Clients" so it's many-to-many so I keep track of clients events in a different table.

The problem is that I can't figured out how to choose the key and the index so the queries will be with best performance.

The table with Key:

```
CREATE TABLE project_clients_events(
    id timeuuid,
    user_id int,
    project_id int,
    client_id text,
    event text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((user_id, project_id), id, client_id)
);
```

Now there will be more then 100K of events per (user_id, project_id) so I need to be able to paginate throw the result:
http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/paging_c.html

How can I group the results and paginate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let me answer your question in two parts. First the pagination and then the partition key

Cassandra CQL driver supports **automatic paging** now, so you need not worry about designing a complex where clause.

```
Statement stmt = new SimpleStatement("SELECT * FROM images");
stmt.setFetchSize(100);
ResultSet rs = session.execute(stmt);

// Iterate over the ResultSet here
```

This link will be helpful :
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/client-side-improvements-in-cassandra-2-0

Deciding the partition depends on the queries you may have. For example if most of your queries use the user_id and project_id (i.e. most of your queries fetch results only based on user_id and client_id) then it’s better to have then as a part of the partition key, as all those results will be placed in the same Cassandra column (on the same node) and fetched together.

Hence I would advise you to first decide the queries and select your partition keys accordingly. As your **performance will depend on what the queries are vs. how the columns are stored** in Cassandra

This could help you http://www.slideshare.net/DataStax/understanding-how-cql3-maps-to-cassandras-internal-data-structure (slides 45-70)

Comment: I'm using PHP there isn't anything that auto paginate and CQL 3 offers it this way: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/paging_c.html the problem is that I want the key will be (user_id, project_id) but how can I keep reading from the last position?